# Lumpy soil and grass

Tags: soil, grass

I live in an area with a clay soil and it tends to make hard clumps. So, when walking across grass, the ground is uneven and very lumpy. Is there any way to smooth it out and help the grass feel flat?

Comment: Yes, but it involves spreading sieved or  fine topsoil over the area to fill in hollows as well other autumn lawn maintenance...  is this a lawn or just rough grass? If its a lawn, is it otherwise in good health, not full of weeds? What type of grass is it?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling is common in areas with freeze/thaw moving soil. If you co not have freezing weather , one rolling should smooth it.

Comment: Hmm, it is hard to imagine rolling smoothing out the lumps. They are small and hard.

Comment: The rollers that I am familiar with contain water and  weigh a few hundred pounds, pulled by riding mower.